# Midpoint circle algorithm - explanation of change inequality sign at wikipedia

Tags: algorithms

I try to analize "[Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)", currently I think I understand every step described on wikipedia but I stuck at some point where inequality changes from "less than" to "more than" (see image below). Then what am I missing here?

[wikipedia equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn5Ci.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay close attention to the term $\left(1 - 2x_{j}\right)$. Since this quantity is negative and the author divides the last expression which was $< 0$ by $\left(1 - 2x_{j}\right)$, the inequality has to change, thus turning into $>0$

Comment: Let assume (1−2xj) has unknown sign in whatever scenario, then how do we know when to change inequality? Or then its not allowed to divide if its unknown?

Comment: If you dont know the sign, you should probably divide in cases. The only time you are not allowed to divide, is if you are dividing by zero

Comment: but if sign is negative but unknown and divide anyway without changing inequality then I might get incorrect result?